# Why does this scatter plot only plot one point?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am following the tutorial [here](https://github.com/ogrisel/parallel_ml_tutorial/blob/master/rendered_notebooks/07%20-%20Text%20Feature%20Extraction%20for%20Classification%20and%20Clustering.ipynb) to classify documents. I am having a problem with this block of code:

```
from itertools import cycle

colors = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k']
for i, c in zip(np.unique(y_train), cycle(colors)):
    plt.scatter(X_train_small_pca[y_train == i, 0],
               X_train_small_pca[y_train == i, 1],
               c=c, label=twenty_train_small.target_names[i], alpha=0.5)

_ = plt.legend(loc='best')
```

I am expecting a scatter plot similar to the example in the tutorial with a lot of date points. Instead, I receive one data point.

My `X_train_small_pca` looks like this:

```
array([[ 0.3310974 , -0.07091423],
       [ 0.39871607, -0.26434965],
       [ 0.47174667, -0.22348895],
       ..., 
       [ 0.49631973,  0.12411882],
       [ 0.36678049,  0.24062078],
       [ 0.22540712, -0.1105503 ]])
```

The `zip` line produces this, which is iterated through:

```
[(u'alt.atheism', 'b'),
 (u'talk.religion.misc', 'g'),
 (u'comp.graphics', 'r'),
 (u'sci.space', 'c')]
```

Finally, I put a `print` line immediately after the `for` loop begins, and I get this output:

```
(u'alt.atheism', 0.33109737451727428, -0.070908715239074438)
(u'talk.religion.misc', 0.33109737451727428, -0.070908715239074438)
(u'comp.graphics', 0.33109737451727428, -0.070908715239074438)
(u'sci.space', 0.33109737451727428, -0.070908715239074438)
```

Why is my scatter plot only seeing the single point for all categories and why is it only seeing 4 total lines, instead of all of my `X_train_small_pca`, which is the expected size?

Comment: I am not familiar with the plot API but I believe that you are creating a number of plots (1 per point), each overwriting the previous (that's why you endup with 1 point, the last). Consider calling `plt.scatter` with the vector of points and colours only once.

Comment: @simpel01 having used `scatter` a few times I don't _think_ it works like that, but I'm not sure. At any rate the `print` statement output shows that the problem is not with `scatter`, it lies in the iteration somehow. NewGuy, what is the contents of `y_train`? Can you edit your question to include a complete example (with shortened `X_train_small_pca` and `y_train` arrays, maybe just four entries or so) that demonstrates the problem and can be copied and pasted?

Comment: @DavidZ: Thing is, though, that NewGuy copy-pasted the code exactly from the tutorial (it's about halfway down the page). I can't see any issue except *maybe* that this output depends on executing prior commands in the tutorial.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman guess I should have checked the link then. Whoops. Let me see....

Comment: Well, I've downloaded the tutorial files and run the relevant cells (and only those cells). I can't reproduce this error. So it seems unlikely that this problem is a result of forgetting to run something earlier in the tutorial. If you'd forgotten to execute a prerequisite cell, you'd get a `NameError`. I'm out of ideas, unless you can provide a small code sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to trim this down and/or include the data. The `X_train_small_pca` is pretty long as is the `y_train` list.